# Extract lines not connected to railway network

Tags: qgis, extract

I want to extract the lines which are not connected to whole railway system (see picture). These are smaller service and leisure lines of minor importance. I thought about something like "has not a neighbour" to get these lines out. I work with QGIS.

How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? How do you want to achieve this? Because right now "manually select and delete" would be a viable answer.

Comment: Does the "not connected" ones each consist of only one feature? For example the diagonal one in the middle of your screenshot, is it only one segment or multiple?

Comment: this section is just an example. It is too much for manual select and delete. @Erik

Comment: not necessarily, sometimes yes sometims no... @BERA

Answer (score 1):

Use [Select by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#selecting-features) with this expression, then delete the selected features (= those which are disjoint/do not touch/intersect/cross other lines):

```
overlay_disjoint (@layer)
```

[image]

Comment: sounds good but QGIS just works for ever and no response at some point. I keep trying something else

Comment: Maybe the layer is too large. Do you have a spatial index?

Comment: Does `overlay_disjoint (@layer)` work (see edited answer).

Answer (score 0):

1. Run [Select by location](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#automatic-selection), choose twice your line layer and check the box next to `touch` as geometric predicate. It selects all the **connected** lines.
2. Click invert feature selection and delete them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

1. Dissolve the line layer with option "keep disjoint features separate"
2. Join attributes by nearest with the dissolve output as input layer 1 and 2. I use maximum distance 10 m.
3. You will now have the attribute n which is the number of nearby lines. It will be NULL for isolated features.
4. Select or extract by attributes `"n" is null`

[image]